# Find Power Series

Tags: calculus

I'm studying *Power Series* and  *Taylor/MacLaurin* series and I came up to one exercise that I don't know if I'm doing right.

It is a multipart exercise with 3 question.

**1** Find the *power series* of $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+4x^2}$ and the points where the development is valid

**2** Find the *power series* of $g(x)=arctan(2x)$ and the points where the development is valid

**3** Using *2* determine $g^{(2011)}(0)$ and $g^{(2012)}(0)$ in $x=0$

For **1** I have done this:
$$\frac{1}{1+4x^2} == \frac{1}{1-(-4x^2)} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-4x^2)^n$$

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-4x^2)^n = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(2^2x^2)^n = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(2x)^{2n}$$

so the development is valid in $x=]-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}[$ since $\left | (-4x^2) \right |<1$

For **2** I have done this:

$$g^{'}(x) = g^{'}(arctan(2x)) = \frac{2}{1+4x^2} = 2\frac{1}{1+4x^2}$$

$$2\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(2x)^{2n} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(2)^{2n+1}(x)^{2n}$$

First, I want to know if what I have done is OK and any help on solving **3** because I don't understand how it is done.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that in both cases, your Taylor series is around $x_0 = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If $\phi$ is analytic at $x=0$, then
$$\phi(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\phi^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n$$
for arbitary small $x$. And you show that
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}(2x)^{2n+1}.$$

Comment: thanks but I don't understand. How do you came up with your $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}(2x)^{2n+1}$? My calculations for 1 and 2 where right?

Comment: @Favolas $\tan^{-1} x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} x^{2n+1}$ for $|x|<1$. See [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Infinite_series)

Comment: Tanks. OK but still don't know ho to solve 3.

Comment: $g^{2011}(0)=(-1)^{1005}*2^{2011}*2010!$?

Comment: @Favolas Yes. you are correct.

Comment: Thanks. Was struggling a bit. Forgot the integration part

Comment: Note that functions cannot be analytic at a single point.

Comment: @DominikS I mean a function is analytic over a point for the function is analytic over a neighborhood of the point.